# Зацикливается код

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему происходит зацикливание:

```
def analitik():
    #try:
        f = open("data.log", "r")
        t = [] #тип соеденения
        p = [] #порт
        h = [] #хост
        s = [] #состояние соеденения
        p = [] #процесс
        #print(f)
        temp_p = 0
        for x in f.readlines():
            x = x.split(',')
            x[0] = x[0].replace('\n','')
            #print(x, len(x))
            if (len(x) == 1):
                if(temp_p == 0): #зацикливается
                    p.append(x[0])
                    temp_p = 555
                else:
                    print("все", temp_p)
                    #exit()
                print(len(p))
                print(temp_p)
                for k in range(len(p)):
                    print(p[k],"бебеб")
                    print(str(x))
                    if(p[k] != x):
                        p.append(x)

        print(p)



    #except:
    #    print("Что-то пошло не так.")

analitik()
```

Содержимое файла:

```
TCP,127.0.0.1:58611,DESKTOP-76KCVG8:49678,ESTABLISHED,416
chrome.exe
TCP,127.0.0.1:58616,DESKTOP-76KCVG8:49678,ESTABLISHED,416
chrome.exe
TCP,127.0.0.1:58617,DESKTOP-76KCVG8:49678,ESTABLISHED,416
chrome.exe
TCP,127.0.0.1:58618,DESKTOP-76KCVG8:49678,ESTABLISHED,416
chrome.exe
```

Спасибо.

Ps Мне нужно обработать содержимое файла, и выяснить самые популярны процессы, посещаемые сайты и т.д.

Comment: У вас "#зацикливается" написано не в строке с оператором цикла...

Comment: Да, все правильно. Этот флаг почему-то не срабатывает. Т.е. когда переменная temp!=0 это условие не должно срабатывать и вроде все корректно. Видимо я неправильно выразился, происходит не зацикливание, а некорректная работа флага.

Comment: Тогда отладчик берите и смотрите что там реально происходит и почему.

Comment: Спасибо большое, не знал что так можно. А пока, кто-нибудь, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка.